# How to convert a nested map to a list<Object>

Tags: java, list, hashmap

How to convert a nested map to a list:

the map is:

```
Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Map<String, Double>>> list
```

the Object class is:

```
public class employee {
private Integer id;
private Integer number;
private String  name;
private Double  salary;
```

How to convert the nested map to the List?

Comment: List? What list?

Comment: what list? what number? what does the map contain? what is the key, the value?

Comment: Good idea! Converting from a map structure that I don’t know how has come about and will be difficult to work with for most purposes, to a nice object-oriented design.

Comment: PS If you are sure there are no nulls in your maps, you should prefer to use primitive `int` and `double` inside your class (not `Integer` nor `Double`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate over the map entries. For each inner map, also iterate over its entries, etc. For each entry in the innermost map, create an `Employee` and add it to your list.

The standard way to iterate over a map is to iterate over its entry set. vefthym’s answer shows you how to do this with a `for` loop. You may eloborate that code into what you need.

You may also do it with streams, provided you can use Java 8. I am assuming that your outer map maps from ID to an intermediate map (I would expect that intermediate map to hold exactly one entry; but my code will also work with more or fewer). The next map maps from number to a map from name to salary.

```
    List<Employee> empls = list.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .flatMap(oe -> oe.getValue()
                    .entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .flatMap((Map.Entry<Integer, Map<String, Double>> me) -> me.getValue()
                            .entrySet()
                            .stream()
                            .map((Map.Entry<String, Double> ie)
                                    -> new Employee(oe.getKey(), me.getKey(), ie.getKey(), ie.getValue()))))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

That was meant to be `oe` for outer entry, that is, entry in the outer map. Similarly `me` for middle entry and `ie` for inner entry. I have renamed your class to begin with a capital `E` to follow Java naming conventions, and I have assumed a convenient constructor.

EDIT: vefthym, where did your answer go now that I was referring to it? I know you were not too happy about it yourself, it’s fair enough. In any case, the standard way to iterate over a map with a `for` loop is:

```
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> currentEntry : yourMap.entrySet()) {
        // do your stuff here
        // use currentEntry.getKey() and currentEntry.getValue() to get the key and value from the current entry
    }
```

You need to repeat the type arguments from your map declaration in the `<>` after `Map.Entry`.

Comment: Your answer exactly solved my problem, thank you very much!!